# calculate SUM for single column with DbFlow

Tags: android, database, dbflow

I'm using latest version of `DBFLOW` library and i'm trying to calculate sum single column as `countOfNewPosts`

this is my table:

```
public class CafeWebNewPostInformation extends BaseModel {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    public int id;

    @Column
    public int cafeWebServerId;

    @Column
    public int countOfNewPosts;

    @Column
    @ForeignKey(tableClass = AlachiqCafeWebs.class,
            references = @ForeignKeyReference(columnName = "parentId", foreignKeyColumnName = "id"))
    private int parentId;

    @Column
    public int lastSavedId;

    @Column
    public int lastRequestedId;

    @Column
    public int lastRetrievedId;
}
```

and this is my code to get that from this table:

```
CafeWebNewPostInformation countOfNewPost =
        SQLite.select(
                Method.sum(CafeWebNewPostInformation_Table.countOfNewPosts).as("count")
        )
                .from(CafeWebNewPostInformation.class).querySingle();
```

i dont get any error and this is result of that:

ScreenShot:

[image]

what happen and where is  `count` on this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

problem solved

think about it. you are calling

```
SELECT SUM(`countOfNewPosts`) as 'count' FROM `CafeWebNewPostInformation`
```

Meaning the results you get back only contain a single row of count from that query. You wont get any error since we don't implement strict column matching on a Cursor. You need to define a `@QueryModel` [QueryModels](https://agrosner.gitbooks.io/dbflow/content/QueryModels.html) that has a single field called count:

```
@QueryModel // (add database reference)
public class CountOfPost {

  @Column
  public int count;
}
```

then

```
CountOfPost count = SQLite.select(
  Method.sum(CafeWebNewPostInformation_Table.countOfNewPosts).as("count"))
  .from(CafeWebNewPostInformation.class)
  .queryCustomSingle(CountOfPost.class);
```

or you can instead of calling `querySingle()` call `count()`.

[reference](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/issues/1390)